# Make LUKS play nicely with a Ubuntu 18.04 installed *after* a 19.04

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, luks

So I have been steadily updating my laptop, for a year and half, up to the 19.04 quite recently.

My issue is that now I need to use an application which only works with the 18.04 LTS. I am happy with 19.04 but I would need from time to time to use the 18.04. I figured that easiest way would be to install it. My starting point is a full disk encryption (LVM + LUKS). From this state I pluggedin the installation USB and started the Ubuntu installation.

Installer doesn't seem to recognize the LUKS and the wizard doesn't give fancy options for it. When booted from USB (in "Try Ubuntu) I...:

- Activated the LUKS --from the `Disks` GUI application.
- Created a new logical volume --with `lvresize` and `lvcreate`.
- Installed the system to this new volume --regular installation wizard.

However, the GRUB is completely broken. Installation wizard failed at the grub stage, and when I tried (after a reboot) to do an `update-grub` from the 19.04 it recognizes the 18.04, configures it, but doesn't work at boot time. I tried to copy files from the 18.04 /boot folder into the non-encrypted /boot (standard in LUKS installations AFAIK) but had no luck.

I was able to boot the 18.04 by:

- Copying the `/lib/modules` and `/lib/modprobe.d` from the 19.04 into the 18.04
- Using the same grub configuration from 19.04 but changing the root device.
- Editing the `fstab` in the 18.04

The system boots, I can work, but... it seems fragile. I assume I cannot rely on updates working, given that 18.04 boots because the manual edits. And the mismatch between used kernel and expected kernel may be a problem down the road.

Is there a standard and easy procedure to achieve what I want? The 19.04 is untouchable, but I am ready to repartition or reinstall anything related to the 18.04. I came here looking for ideas / advise / approaches for a *proper way*, if there is one.